# Pass a list of type to component and display it

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Some code samples will explain what I am attempting to accomplish quite easily:

Top Level Page:

```
<Test Items="users" />

@code {

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> users { get; set; } = new (){
        new User{
            Id = 1,
            Username = "Me",
        },
        new User{
            Id = 2,
            Username = "You",
        }
    }; 
}
```

and then in Test.razor:

```
<h3>Test</h3>

@{
    if (Users != null)
    {
        @foreach (var user in Users)
        {
            <div>
                @user.Username
            </div>
        }
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

However, the compiler returns the following error:

The type or namespace name 'User' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What do I need to modify in the above to correctly make the child component aware the User the in the top level page?

Comment: Are you trying to pass a generic list to Test?

Answer (score 3):

Test.razor should look like this

1. In your code `User` is within the Razor compiler top level class - in my case this is `Index.razor` so is referenced as `Index.User`.  To make is available directly, move it to a separate class file.
2. Your Parameter is named incorrectly.  It should be `Items` if you use `<Test Items="users" />`

```cs
<h3>Test</h3>

@{
    if (Items != null)
    {
        @foreach (var user in Items)
        {
            <div>
                @user.Username
            </div>
        }
    }
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Index.User>? Items { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
@page "/"

<Test Items="users" />

@code {

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Username { get; set; }
    }

    public List<User> users { get; set; } = new (){
        new User{
            Id = 1,
            Username = "Me",
        },
        new User{
            Id = 2,
            Username = "You",
        }
    }; 
}
```

Comment: [polite] Do you think it's a good idea to use `Index.User` as a type specifier ?

Comment: Absolutely not,  In general **VERY BAD** code practice, but the question was: "What do I need to modify in the above to correctly make the child component aware the User the in the top level page?"  Without the full context I wasn't going to judge.   And did give a bit of a pointer with -"To make is available directly, move it to a separate class file."

Comment: Right as usual, and the moral of it... I'll give you a pointer... This guy has started from the end. He has copied some code that creates a Data Grid, but he can't go beyond this as he lacks the basic. What he's trying to do now is to understand how to pass a list of users and display it. He needs it in order to understand this: `<DataTableColumn TRowData="User" Expression="u => u.Id"/>` and this: `[Parameter] public ICollection<TRowData> Items { get; set; }` Note that these code snippets are from his previous question. That is why in my answer I use a generic parameter.. but seems to no avail